# Convert a website to a mobile website

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I just finished my website. And when i visit the site with a desktop browser, it looks nice.
But when i visit the site with a mobile device, the site is illegible...

So i want a mobile version of my website. 
But i don't want to study mobile web developing just for one site... so it must be easy for a layman like me!

i search allready in google, but only found some tutorials. and these tutorials are really hard for me... 
i search something like a tool or a team who convert it for me. i also pay something for it!

thank you for answering

Comment: You could use something like twitter bottstrap to quickly setup your site - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ Here's another tool to make it easier - http://jetstrap.com/

Comment: Its hard to develop an existing site into mobile. It is much easier to build the project with mobile in mind. I would suggest using a framework such as 960gs to make this easier for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I start to develop websites, I just develop websites for big screens. But in these times with so many mobile devices, you must be able to develop mobile websites as a web developer.

Of much help to me was the website http://www.dudamobile.com/index.php.
It converts your website to a mobile view. Not perfect, but a very good basis. For free.

When you are inexperienced with mobile developing, google for tips.

http://jquerymobile.com/ has some information for the mobile version of jQuery. Or just ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks for the site! it's really easy for the basics! i'll use it and costumize it with some help by google 
and to detect i use the code by Christopher :)

Comment: Works great. The only issue is, I have ASPX pages and when using SELECT or SEARCHING the site does not respond.

Comment: Is it possible to download the template after designing

Answer (score 11):

What you can do is, use javascript or css to detect the width of the screen.

Then with the detected results you use either your Desktop CSS or Mobile CSS. That'll be the quickest way, obviously you will need to create a seperate CSS file for mobile and construct it for mobile.

Here's how you can detect:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 601px)" href="desktop.css" />
```

Comment: Most easiest way to convert a website into mobile website

Comment: thanks for the code!
i'll use the site by dTDesign and use your code :)

Comment: oh man, i can't mark you both for the accept answer...